# How to use fcm-django?

Tags: django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm just new in django-fcm. Can anyone give a  step by step how to setup django-fcm package ? I want to push notification to web browser, when user allow notification from my website.
Thank You

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.